# PHP script continuing to run after page close [initiated from AJAX]

Tags: php, ajax, execute, continuous

Everything I google tells me this should *not* be happening, however it is.

I'm building a migration tool to build a 'master database'. I have an admin panel, only accessible to a few select people. There is a merge button that starts an AJAX call to run the migration php function. I'm not positive how long this script takes considering I'm still developing it but none the less I'm expecting a minimum of 20 minutes once pushed to production and populated with the production database. I do NOT need a lecture on best practices telling me not to do it via a GUI. This will become a cron as well, however I want to be able to induce it manually, if the admin desires.

So here's my process. The migration function immediately closes the session `session_write_close()` allowing me to run multiple php scripts simultaneously. I do this because I start a setInterval that checks to see a session variable. This is my 'progress' which is just an int on what loop iteration I'm on. In my migration script I open sessions, add 1 to that int, and close the sessions again. I do this at the end of each loop.

By doing this I have successfully created a progress for my AJAX. Now I noticed something. If I start my migration, then close out of my tab - or refresh. Once I reload the page my progress continues to grow. This tells me that the migration script is still executing in the background.

If I close 100% out of my browser, or clear my sessions I no longer see progress go up. This however is not because the script stops. This is because my progress indication relies on sessions and once I clear my sessions or close out my browser my session cookie changes. However I *know* the script is still running because I can query the database manually and see that entries are being added.

NOW to my question:
I do NOT want this. If my browser closes, if I press refresh, if I loose connection, etc I want the script to be TERMINATED. I want it to stop mid process.

I tried ignore_user_abort(false); however I'm pretty sure this is specific to command line and made no difference for me.

I want it to be terminated because I'm building a 'progress resume' function where we can choose where to resume the migration progress again.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I didn't want to go this route but some solution I just though of is I could have another session variable. And it's my 'last time client was validated' which could be a timestamp. In my javascript, on the client side, every like 30 seconds I could hit a php script to 'update last time client was validated'. And in my migration function at the beginning of each loop I could check to make sure that timestamp isn't like 60 seconds old for example. If it IS 60 seconds old, or older, I do a die thus stopping my script. This would locally mean 'if there is no client updating this timestamp then we can assume the user closed out of his browser/tab/refreshed'. And as for the function I can ignore this check if in command line (cron). Not the ideal solution but it is my plan B

Comment: This is not really possible to do - not easily anyway. Once a PHP script is executed, it goes until it stops or is told to stop by you. And closing a browser tab is not enough to do this. You can abort AJAX calls, but this is different and still won't do what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: segment the migration process into many smaller steps. Write a manager and poll that for process and have that receive the begin/stop/restart commands.

Comment: Can`t you check with http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php ?

Comment: @dgig That is actually not true, in contrary. The execution of a php script will be terminated immediately if the client disconnects, _if php is used as a module inside the http server environment_, which is the usual case. That is indeed different if another method is used, like cgi or fastcgi. That is why the function `ignore_client_abort()` exists, actually...

Comment: Could it be that it is not actually the php script still executing, but the database server still processing?

Comment: Hm, interesting. I'll have to check into this. Thanks @arkascha

Comment: There is a [ignore-user-abort](http://php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort) setting which could've been set to `true` (or `on`, `1`). Though I suspect @arkascha's pointer that the query is still running to be correct.

Comment: I added `if(connection_aborted()){
     mail('my_email@email.com', 'aborted', 'ahhh');
     die();
    }` to the beginning of my loop and this made no difference. The script continued to run.

Comment: @arkascha the function ignore_client_abort() does not exist, I did however try ignore_user_abort(false); with both true and false passed in, both with no success.

Comment: I suspect you two are right, I don't believe this is a php problem more of a mysql problem. The whole purpose of this function is migrating data so there are constant selects, inserts, and updates being ran.

Comment: @dgig you can trick the script to read changes in session that were made during it's execution. I achieved it by doing a loop that closes the session, sleeps for a few seconds, then wakes up and continues the session. This way the script can do it's thing for a long time and then sleep for one second to check changes in session from other sources.
Or you can check for values in database, which are fetched real-time and reflect changes from outside the script execution.

Answer (score 1):

I am, and did, go with the solution to ping from the client to indicate if the client is still alive or not.

So essentially this is what I did:

From the client, in javascript, I set up a setInterval to run every 1.5 seconds and that hits a php script via AJAX. This php script updates a session variable with the current timestamp (this could easily be a database value if you needed to, however I didn't want the overhead of another query).

`$_SESSION['migration_listsync_clientLastPing_'.$decodedJson['progressKey']]    = time();`

Then, inside my migration function I run a check to see if the 'timestamp' is over 10 seconds old, and if it is I die - thus killing the script.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['migration_listsync_clientLastPing_'.$progressKey])){
    $calc = time() - $_SESSION['migration_listsync_clientLastPing_'.$progressKey];
    if($calc > 10){
        die();
    }
}
```

I added a 'progressKey' param which is a random number from 1-100 that is generated when the function is called. This number is generated in javascript and passed into both of my AJAX calls. This way if the user refreshes the page and then immediately pressed the button again we won't have 2 instances of the function running. The 'old' instance will die after a few seconds and the new instance will take over.

This isn't an ideal solution however it is an effective one.